# Querying Offline Files available disk usage

Tags: powershell, script, storage, query, offline-files

Looking for a way to query the *Offline Files* "***available***" disk usage (Windows 10).  The value I want to query is displayed in the Offline Files GUI on the Disk Usage tab.  The value is not based on physical drive size or volume size, it's based on Disk Usage *allocated* to offline files minus the sum size of offline files currently cached.

I prefer a PowerShell method, but ANY method will do.

I've looked at Get-WmiObject win32_offlineFilesCache, and that only gives me basic configuration.

I'm wondering if the value of "available" disk usage for offline files is not a field in the CSC database at all, but rather maybe just a dynamic calculation that runs in memory when called, so can't be query'd directly... If that's true (which I don't know if it is), then I need to find a way to query the setting for Total Disk Usage allocated to Offline Files, then get a file size SUM of all files currently in the Offline Files cache.

Thanks...

Comment: The available space for offline files is the "Max size of the offline files cache" less the size of the cache. The max size is defined in group policy.

Comment: correct, but how do I query those values,,, I know how to look them up manually on a computer, I'm trying to figure out how to query them via scripting so I can generate reports.